# how to set pop/smtp in php.ini

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email using GMail SMTP server from PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

i have a mac and i was wondering how i can set pop/smtp using gmails information in php.ini ?
i have version: 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP just uses the local MTA for mail delivery. Configure Postfix to use Gmail as a relay.